# Converting dates to datetime64 results in day and month places getting swapped

Tags: python, datetime

I am pulling a time series from a csv file which has dates in "mm/dd/yyyy" format

```
df = pd.read_csv(lib_file.csv)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x,'%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

below is the output

[image]

I convert dtypes for ['Date'] from object to datetime64

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

but that changes my dates as well

[image]

how do I fix it?

Comment: How are the two related? Why do you use Python standard lib's datetime.strptime in the first example and pd.to_datetime in the second? If you work with pandas, use pandas functionality whenever possible, but note: if you don't specify a format for pd.to_datetime, it assumes that the month comes first. You have kwarg `dayfirst` to account for that, check [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).

Comment: agreed, it just got muddled there. Removing dayfirst and and not using  datetime.strptime it fixed the problem. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

This will infer your dates based on the first non-NaN element which is being correctly parsed in your case and will not infer the format for each and every row of the dataframe.

Comment: thanks @kkgarg, however the original problem was not solved by your code unfortunately, but I could fix the issue by amending my codes as stated above.

Comment: it'll be good if you post your solution in case others face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

just using the below code helped

```
df = pd.read_csv(lib_file.csv)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date])
```